# How to connect to an AWS RDS MYSQL from an Amazon UX instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, database-connection

Problem explanation:  Not able to connect to RDS-MYSQL instance from another EC2 instance. The other instance is an Amazon-Unix.

listed below are the things tried.

1. Checked the security group [allowed all].
2. Was trying to install MYSQL monitor.It wasn't successful.
3. Installed PHP, httpd successfully.
4. Updated my connect.php with the username password, dbname and with the endpoint details already.
5. Error message "mysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host".

Comment: could you at least format your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean Amazon RDS instance and you have MySQL DB installed on it. If that's what you are asking, you don't have access to instance level in AWS RDS, only DB level access is permitted. The instance is maintained by AWS, so that you can focus on the DB side.

Comment: thanks Amitabh!! i was looking for very basic answer .  I am trying to  connect to the DB instance  from an another EC2 instance. I latter figured it out that by installing yum install mysql -y and gave the user name , password and the end point and then i was able to connect to my instance .

Comment: yep, that's what I said: 'DB level access is permitted'. I guess you solved your query...